# I am trying to map the countries on the world map. The problem occurring is only USA is being shown on the output

Tags: python, plotly, geopandas

```
fig = px.scatter_geo(df, locations="country", color = "country",
                                  projection="natural earth")
fig.show()
```

On the output side, I am able to get the world map and in the legends, all the countries do appear. The problem is the countries are not shown on the map.

Here is the snap of the sample data:

```
{'id': {0: '72b83200-4881-4806-b910-af86905256c4',
  1: '5db5df19-c06b-489a-b2f4-c2ffc26643ba',
  2: '6c9e4f0d-ef87-497f-97af-df207a25331d',
  3: '004bf779-368d-47ae-b3cc-07b0ecad2464',
  4: '8a2265d9-1f81-4c47-953f-0d4bfab326c0'},
 'name': {0: 'BALCO BRANDS PTY LTD',
  1: 'Bambury',
  2: 'Bata Shoe Company of Australia',
  3: 'Bean Body Care',
  4: 'Caprice Australia '},
 'canonical_name': {0: 'balcobrands',
  1: 'bambury',
  2: 'batashoecompanyofaustralia',
  3: 'beanbodycare',
  4: 'capriceaustralia'},
 'url': {0: 'http://www.balcobrands.com',
  1: 'http://www.bambury.com.au',
  2: 'http://www.bataindustrials.com.au',
  3: 'https://global.beanbodycare.com',
  4: 'http://www.caprice.com.au'},
 'type': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3},
 'address': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'city': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'state': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'country': {0: 'Australia',
  1: 'Australia',
  2: 'Australia',
  3: 'Australia',
  4: 'Australia'},
 'country_code': {0: 'AU', 1: 'AU', 2: 'AU', 3: 'AU', 4: 'AU'},
 'created_at': {0: '2020-04-01 20:52:38.098099',
  1: '2020-04-01 20:52:38.364935',
  2: '2020-04-01 20:52:38.636768',
  3: '2020-04-01 20:52:38.951573',
  4: '2020-04-01 20:52:39.271376'},
 'created_by': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'updated_at': {0: '2020-04-01 20:52:38.098099',
  1: '2020-04-01 20:52:38.364935',
  2: '2020-04-01 20:52:38.636768',
  3: '2020-04-01 20:52:38.951573',
  4: '2020-04-01 20:52:39.271376'},
 'updated_by': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}}
```

Comment: Hi, do you mind to share a sample of your data?

Comment: I have added a snap of the sample data in the question.

Comment: You better add the output of df.head().to_dict()

Comment: I have added the output of df.head().to_dict()

Answer (score 0):

The data did not contain the three-digit country codes. When the data was merged with another dataset having three-digit country codes, the required output was obtained.